# cannot retrieve dataframe in shelve

Tags: pandas

I saved two dataframes onto a `shelve` database using a previous Pandas version (unsure which one, but likely 0.25.3), and have no problems reading them from the `shelve` file with Pandas 0.25.3.  However, I cannot read them with the latest Pandas (1.0.0, as printed by pandas.**version**).  I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FrozenNDArray' on <module 'pandas.core.indexes.frozen' from 'local/virtualenv.../'
```

It seems the `FrozenNDArray` class has been removed in 1.0.0, so how can I recover the dataframes?  Some searches point to `pandas.read_pickle`, but nothing equivalent for `shelve`.

Comment: same here. looks like the usual upgrade problems when using pickle. i think reading in old pandas, writing in something independent, reading & writing with new pickle / panda /numpy could help, but haven't done yet, still looking for a simpler method....

Comment: I had the same problem. I used ``pandas=0.25`` to save the DataFrames to disk with parquet and read, pickled them again with ``pandas=1.0.1``. Now, they even work for ``pandas=0.25``. I did not expect backward compatibility, but maybe you know why.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but I solved the same problem by loading my pickle file with:

```
pd.read_pickle(x)
```

where x should be your file handler.

Comment: It is great it can read any pickle and not just a pickle with a single DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks @Dr_Zaszuś! I am glad you find this helpful.